# Send JSON and redirect with Passport authenticate

Tags: redirect, express, server, passport.js

I'm working with ExpressJS and Passport to authenticate local users, and ideally I want to reply with both a JSON object and a redirect upon success or failure.  My code right now looks like this:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-signin', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      res.json(false);
      return res.redirect('/signin');
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.json(user);
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  })
  (req, res, next);
});
```

The problem is that res.json() and res.redirect() both cause the response to become Finished.  Is there some way to have the two happen together?  The reason I want to send JSON as well as a redirect is that the login also needs to work from a mobile app, for which redirect doesn't seem to do anything.

If there are better ways to accomplish that, that'd be great too, but the additional info I want to send as JSON would be helpful on the website side too.

Thanks!

EDIT: It looks like I can work with 2 separate routes, however, I'd still like to know if it's possible to both send JSON and redirect.

Comment: What are you using for front-end?

Comment: HTML/CSS/JS.  I'm not clear what the mobile app developers are using; I believe Java (Android) and Swift (iOS)?